# SQLite Join OperationalError

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy

When running this SQL code with join, I got an error:

```
    ss=  'select project.id from  project_list pl  '
    ss+= ' LEFT JOIN project p ON pl.project_id = p.id  '
    ss+= ' LEFT JOIN table t   ON pl.table_id   = t.id  '
```

Error is  :

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "table": 
syntax error [SQL: 'select project.id from  project_list pl  
 LEFT JOIN project p ON pl.project_id = p.id   LEFT JOIN table t 
ON pl.table_id   = t.id  ']
```

This is not where the error comes from since the SQL statement looks correct.
This is using SQL Alchemy.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table named `table`, you need to quote it, or it causes a parsing error. This will work:

```
ss=  'select project.id from  project_list pl  '
ss+= ' LEFT JOIN project p ON pl.project_id = p.id  '
ss+= ' LEFT JOIN "table" t   ON pl.table_id   = t.id  '
```

This is because `table` is a reserved word in SQL (e.g. `create table my_table`, `alter table mytable`, etc.), and either the SQL parser is primitive, or the spec demands that it behave this way (PostgreSQL has the same problem).

I strongly encourage you to rename `table` to something else, if you can, or you're going to be in for a world of hurt. In other scenarios with SQLAlchemy or other DB libraries, when you're not hand-crafting the SQL, they may not be smart enough to automatically quote the table name. This will also cause you headaches if you migrate from SQLite to another database. It's likely to confuse people reading the code.